# Java: Clone contents of stringbuilder and append item to each row all

Tags: java, csv

How can I clone contents of Stringbuilder based on number of records and append record to each row of cloned contents. I'm trying to write data to CSV in way each rows have duplicate columns values repeated by times size of records.

Sample Output CSV should look like.

```
CN1| CN2| CN3
 1    b    c
 1    d    f
 2    g    h
```

Here's sample Java Code I'm using

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CSVWrite {
public static Map<String, List<Records>> getData() {

    Map<String, List<Records>> fields = new HashMap<>();

    List<Records> records_1 = new ArrayList<>();

    Records sample_1 = new Records();
    sample_1.setName("b");
    sample_1.setId("c");

    Records sample_2 = new Records();
    sample_2.setName("d");
    sample_2.setId("f");

    records_1.add(sample_1);
    records_1.add(sample_2);

    List<Records> records_2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Records sample_3 = new Records();
    sample_1.setName("g");
    sample_1.setId("h");

    records_2.add(sample_3);

    fields.put("1", records_1);
    fields.put("2", records_2);

    return fields;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CSVWrite write = new CSVWrite();
    String csvString = write.getCsvString();
    String expectedString = "1,b,c\n" + "1,d,f\n" + "2,g,h";
    System.out.println(csvString.equals(expectedString));
}

public String getCsvString() {
    Map<String, List<Records>> fields = CSVWrite.getData();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Records>> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(entry.getKey());
        List<Records> records = entry.getValue();

        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            // how to clone contents of sb repeated times based on records size and append
            // record items to all.
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Unclear to me what you want to clone. The three expected output lines are different from each-other.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. You only use _ in SOME_CONSTANT.

Comment: It is totally unclear to mean what exactly is the problem here. What do you want to clone? When do you want to clone it? In your example only the value `1` appears twice and I have no idea why.

Comment: I think you should explain to us your question, not in terms of what you think the implementation should be, as that is at [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538). Instead, explain what the input is, and what the output is relative to that input.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an error I think, this code look weird. The var sample_3 is built but not correctly populated:

```
Records sample_3 = new Records();
sample_1.setName("g");
sample_1.setId("h");
```

It should be:

```
Records sample_3 = new Records();
sample_3.setName("g");
sample_3.setId("h");
```

Finally, there is no need to clone anything to achieve the desired result, simply rewrite `getCsvString()` like this:

```
public String getCsvString() {
    Map<String, List<Records>> fields = CSVWrite.getData();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Records>> entry : fields.entrySet()) {
        List<Records> records = entry.getValue();

        for (Records record : records) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey());
            sb.append(",").append(record.getName());
            sb.append(",").append(record.getId());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Those 2 corrections will generate output:

> 1,b,c
>
> 1,d,f
>
> 2,g,h

Comment: Note: in CSV, there is no space after the comma.

Comment: @RealSkeptic OK, fixed. Except that minor detail, does it answer your question ?

Comment: @Benoit This does answers partly, let me update question clearly